# Axios doen't send any data to php

Tags: php, reactjs, axios

I'm using axios in Reactjs to send user's data to php and then create a new user with php,but when I want to send  my data it goes empty and my php side gives some error

My react codes

```
import React, { useReducer } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import UserContext from './userContext';
import userReducer from './userReducer';

  //Register user
const registerUser = async () =>{
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
          }
    };


    const response  = await axios.post('http://localhost/react_cms/api/users/user.php' , {message : 'ppp'} , config);

    console.log(response.data);
}

return (
    <UserContext.Provider 
    value={{

        registerUser
    }}>
    {props.children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
);


}

export default UserState;
```

And my php side codes :

```
<?php
    $message = isset($_GET['message']) ? $_GET['message'] : 'no';

    $data = array ('message' => $message);

    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

The result of this code is :

```
{message : 'no'}
```

Comment: you seem to be performing a `POST` request `axios.post()`, while reading the `$_GET` array with PHP for a `message`. Change `$_GET` to `$_POST` in your PHP file.

Comment: I've done it but that's the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to either change this line

```
$message = isset($_GET['message']) ? $_GET['message'] : 'no';
```

into

```
$message = isset($_POST['message']) ? $_POST['message'] : 'no';
```

or leave it as it is and send a get request by changing your axios call

from

```
const response  = await axios.post('http://localhost/react_cms/api/users/user.php' , {message : 'ppp'} , config);
```

to

```
const response  = await axios.get('http://localhost/react_cms/api/users/user.php?message=ppp', config);
```

Please note that the signature of the `get` method is different than the `post` method in Axios, as the `get` method does not require the data parameter.

It's considered good practice to when sending data to store you use the POST verb, whereas if you are retrieving data for a certain identifier, you may use GET.

Have a look at this documentation for explanations of http verbs that axios can utilize: https://restfulapi.net/http-methods/.

Comment: Thanks so much , I've done it with GET method as you said , but it didn't work with POST method

Comment: @mohammad you're welcome. It might be worth trying to figure out how to get it to work using POST instead, as you're effectively posting data, not retrieving it. So post would be most desirable here.